# argo-cd how to test configuration in a "development" cluster before going live

Tags: kubernetes, argocd, gitops

I have a single argocd repository which contains all the configuration for the Kubernetes cluster. Now I want to work with PRs and only want to merge things which were tested on our continuous integration system before they can be merged. To do so, my idea was to have another cluster which I then deploy the branch to. Sadly, argocd defines the `revision` and `targetRevision` inside its yaml files – therefore, this is “hard-coded” inside git.

What is the best way to switch the revision, so I can “apply” any feature branch and still link it to a cluster?

Target

```
GIT - Branch master    -> prod-Cluster
    - Branch dev       -> dev-Cluster
    - Branch feature.. -> feature-Cluster using kind
```

ArgoCD Config

```
Application (root) -> ApplicationSet (app-of-appset) -> apps/* directory containing kustomization files
```

Example argo config for application set

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: ApplicationSet
metadata:
  name: cluster-addons
spec:
  generators:
  - git:
      repoURL: https://github.com/argoproj-labs/applicationset.git
      revision: HEAD <--------- Thats what I want to adjust for testing
      directories:
      - path: examples/git-generator-directory/cluster-addons/*
  template:
    metadata:
      name: '{{path.basename}}'
    spec:
      project: default
      source:
        repoURL: https://github.com/argoproj-labs/applicationset.git
        targetRevision: HEAD <--------- Thats what I want to adjust for testing
        path: '{{path}}'
      destination:
        server: https://kubernetes.default.svc
        namespace: '{{path.basename}}'
```

Comment: have you found a solution?

Comment: Not really no, I have different folders and different clusters now

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way is to deploy different apps for each branch within the same repo. Look at the following info from [ArgoCD documentation](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/parameters/):

> You can also store parameter overrides in an application specific file, if you are sourcing multiple applications from a single path in your repository.
>
> The application specific file must be named `.argocd-source-<appname>.yaml`, where  is the name of the application the overrides are valid for.
>
> If there exists an non-application specific `.argocd-source.yaml`, parameters included in that file will be merged first, and then the application specific parameters are merged, which can also contain overrides to the parameters stored in the non-application specific file.

Or you can try to patch the application:

`argocd app patch APPNAME --patch '[{"op": "replace", "path": "/spec/template/spec/source/targetRevision", "value": "HEAD"}]'`

and then `argocd app sync APPNAME`

However everything gets difficult when it's hardcoded.

Comment: That was my worst fear I expected something like a config map entry for argo to override the hardcoded git version for testing